# Inner Join one Column multiple search Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know how to do a basic Inner Join query. However because of my data structure I need to get values from multiple tables in order to get the results I need. As of now in order for me to find an offense record I have to pass this query

```
SELECT * FROM OFFENSE  where TRS_IDN IN 
(SELECT TRS_IDN FROM CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.TRS where TRN_IDN IN 
(select TRN_IDN from CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.TRN where IND_IDN = 
(SELECT TOP 1 IND_IDN FROM CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.PERSON WHERE PER_IDN = @PER_IDN)))
```

This results in this:

```
OFF_IDN     TRS_IDN     AGY_TXT     DOO_DTE     AON_COD     AOL_TXT                 LDA_COD GOC_COD  ADN_COD     ADD_TXT     ADA_DTE     REF_TXT     IPN_NBR     ICA_NBR     DMV_COD

23808207    26154505    TX2270000   5/13/2013   54040014    DRIVING WHILE INTOXI    MA               205                     5/14/2013  TX227013A                1320573
```

In the `CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.TRN` table there is a column called `TRN_IDN`. The objective is to inner join the `CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.OFFENSE` table with `CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.TRN` and add the SINGLE COLUMN called `TRN_IDN`. How can I do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the question is but why dont you do the following to clean up the syntax

```
SELECT top 1 o.* ,trs.TRN_IDN
FROM OFFENSE o
inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.TRS  trs on trs.TRS_IDN = o.TRS_IDN 
inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.TRN  trn on trn.TRN_IDN = trs.TRN_IDN 
inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.PERSON  p on p.IND_IDN = trn .IND_IDN 
where p.PER_IDN = @PER_IDN
```

Comment: Awesome buddy this is excatly what I was looking for. The only difference is that I may have many offenses come in so I cant select the ```TOP 1``` I changed that part of the code to ```SELECT o.*, trs.TRN_IDN``` Other wise the code you provided was very clean and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT f1.*, f5.TRN_IDN FROM OFFENSE f1 
cross join 
(
SELECT top 1 f3.TRN_IDN FROM CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.TRS f2 inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.TRN f3 on f2.TRN_IDN=f3.TRN_IDN
inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.PERSON f4 on f3.IND_IDN=f4.IND_IDN
where f1.TRS_IDN =f2.TRS_IDN 
) f5
```

If you want all link , substract top 1

Comment: Hey friend, I tried this code but I get a syntax error. In the WHERE clause it says ```the multi part identifier f1.TRS_IDN could not be found``` I have not done cross joins before so I am having a hard time understanding this code.

Comment: Hi , i use cross join besause i thaught you want first row founded not all rows (you use In operator, this is not the same result and my English is not really good). Solution of H2ORider is correct. But my solution can work its Strange... SELECT f1.*, f5.TRN_IDN FROM OFFENSE f1 
    cross join 
    (
    SELECT top 1 f2.TRN_IDN FROM CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.TRS f2 inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.TRN f3 on f2.TRN_IDN=f3.TRN_IDN
    inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.PERSON f4 on f3.IND_IDN=f4.IND_IDN
    where f1.TRS_IDN =f2.TRS_IDN 
    ) f5

Answer (score 0):

You can simply join your select statement with table`CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.TRN` as your select is mainly from table `CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.OFFENSE` with only the where condition like this

```
SELECT  O.*, 
        TRN.TRN_IDN
FROM    OFFENSE AS O  
JOIN    CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.TRS AS TRS
ON      O.TRS_IDN = TRS.TRS_IDN
JOIN    CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.TRN AS TRN
ON      TRS.TRN_IDN = TRN.TRN_IDN

WHERE O.TRS_IDN IN 
    (SELECT TRS_IDN FROM CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.TRS WHERE TRN_IDN IN 
        (SELECT TRN_IDN FROM CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.TRN WHERE IND_IDN = 
            (SELECT TOP (1) IND_IDN FROM CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.PERSON 
                WHERE PER_IDN = @PER_IDN)))
```